# Process.Start() and continue with my code

Tags: c#, screenshot, process.start

My program is in win forms (c#). It should open an external program, do a printscreen of it's main window, and close it.
By using Process.Start() I can open the the program, but then all the focus is on it and my code is halted. Only when I close it myself my form continues- but it's too late for the screenshot.
So how do I force my code to keep running?

```
    public void Runttk(string maromnum)
    {
        Process runttk = new Process();
        runttk.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;               
        runttk.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\program.exe";
        runttk.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        runttk.Start();
        this.Focus();
        try
        {
            if (runttk.WaitForInputIdle()==true)
            {                                          
                PringJpg(maromnum);
                Killttk();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

    }
```

Thank you

UPDATE:
eventuanlly I've used Thread.Sleep(3000). Crued but do the trick.
I didn't used backgroundworker because the sync between the finale uplaod the the extenral program and my code wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Process.Start() WILL return control to your program immediately. Run it under the debugger or add some Debug.WriteLine() to see where your code is stopping. Perhaps WaitForInputIdle() is not returning until the external program exits?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740038/how-do-i-wait-until-a-console-application-is-idle
So use a synchronization object across processes for that.

Comment: @Duane do you know a good example for threading? I'm new to it.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is pretty straight forward and easy to use, are you using winforms though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying your code, but with another program like notepad.exe, Notepad runs and then control drops through to where you call PringJpg.

So I think the problem is that it is blocking on if (runttk.WaitForInputIdle()==true), please try adding a timeout to this operation.

Comment: Hey as I said the Sebastian the timeout is a problem- I canot predicte how much time it would take.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your programm is never idle - means that `runttk.WaitForInputIdle()==true` let your app wait until you close it.

Add a limit ( for example `runttk.WaitForInputIdle(500)==true`) should fulfill your needings.

Comment: @Sebastian, this check is being made against the running process which is a win forms app, not a console window.

Comment: darn.. did a ninja delete. What I wrote was essentially: Console windows have no (window) UI, therefore they will never enter an InputIdle state and the call to `runttk.WaitForInputIdle()` is blocking.

Comment: @Sebastian: In any case, WaitForInputIdle() will always return IMMEDIATELY if it is a console app. (This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hey it's not console. @Sebastian adding a parameter is problematic becuase I don't know how much time would take for the program to start. When I enter 5000 it prints it in the middle of starting.